# Stubbing Methods does not work with OCMock3.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

Stubbing Methods works nicely With 'NSUserDefaults',but it just doesn't seem to work with My Custom Method.

My test code is as follows:

```
- (void)testExample 
{
    id userDefaultMock = OCMClassMock([NSUserDefaults class]);
    OCMStub([userDefaultMock standardUserDefaults]).andReturn(userDefaultMock);
    OCMStub([userDefaultMock objectForKey:[OCMArg any]]).andReturn(@"user defaults mock obj");


    id managerMock = OCMClassMock([ViewManager class]);
    OCMStub([managerMock sharedInstance]).andReturn(managerMock);
    OCMStub([managerMock generateObjWithObj:[OCMArg any]]).andReturn(@(11));

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc publicMethod];

}
```

code in ViewController:

```
- (void)publicMethod
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"mockObj" forKey:@"mockObjKey"];
    id obj = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mockObjKey"];
    NSLog(@"mockObjKey:%@",obj);

    NSNumber *num = @(0);
    NSNumber *i = [[ViewManager sharedInstance] generateIndexWithNumber:num];
    NSLog(@"i expected to be 1, actual :%ld",i.integerValue);
}
```

code in ViewManager:

```
static ViewManager *sharedViewManager = nil;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    if (nil == sharedViewManager)
    {
        sharedViewManager = [[ViewManager alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedViewManager;
}
- (NSNumber *)generateIndexWithNumber:(NSNumber *)index
{
    NSLog(@"generateIndexWithNumber:%ld",index.integerValue);
    return @(index.integerValue + 1);
}
```

and console output is as follows:

```
2017-07-03 10:12:25.812 OC_Unit[2214:64454] mockObjKey:user defaults mock obj
2017-07-03 10:12:25.812 OC_Unit[2214:64454] generateIndexWithNumber:0
2017-07-03 10:12:25.812 OC_Unit[2214:64454] i expected to be 1, actual :1
```

The last line of output should be 'i expected to be 1, actual :11' if shubbing methods works. I'm wondering，why does it not output as expected。

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are stubbing `generateObjWithObj:` but the code is calling `generateIndexWithNumber:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I'm sorry for pasting the wrong code, code`OCMStub([managerMock generateObjWithObj:[OCMArg any]]).andReturn(@(11));` in `-testExample` should be replaced by `OCMStub([managerMock generateIndexWithNumber:[OCMArg any]]).andReturn(@(11));`.So, I stubbed `generateIndexWithNumber:` actually.

Comment: After testing, I found that `[ViewManager sharedInstance]` in `-publicMethod` won't be replaced by `managerMock`. and if`[ViewManager sharedInstance]` is called in `-testExample` , the replacement happens. Which means I have to replace `sharedViewManager` in `ViewManager` with `managerMock` explicitly to ensure that stubbing custom method works fine. Is this meet your design? Or is there any other way to solve my problem? Best Regards!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a linking issue. Using CocoaPods, or just incorrect target memberships in Xcode, it is possible to create a setup in which the classes under test are included twice. References to `ViewManager` would actually refer to two *separate* *copies* of the class. Then, the test code uses one and creates a stub for it, but the code under test, which was linked differently, uses a different copy of the class. Could you try to print the pointer to the class from the test and from `publicMethod`?

Comment: I added `ViewManager.m` to the 'Compile Sources' in the test target by mistake. Now it's fixed. Thanks a lot.